# Excel slicer not displaying identical values

Tags: database, visualization, spreadsheet, excel-2016, slicers

I am working on a sales data spreadsheet so I created some Excel slicers from the pivot tables I made and I grouped the slicers into weeks, days, prices, quantity, and products so that when I click on the week, for example, it shows me the days, the product and how many quantities was demanded as well as the price of each in their respective slicers, now this is working perfectly.

however, there is a little problem, for example, for days that have an identical number of quantity sold for example 5 oranges were sold on Monday and 5 apples were sold on Tuesday the slicer seems to give me the quantity of one,  it is si[image]milar with the price if the price of a product is the same let's say apples cost $2 and oranges cost same $2 it will only give me the price of one even though the product slicer will display all the products however the prices and quantity slicers having similar values will display only one value so at the end of the day I will have maybe 4 products and 3 prices instead of 4 products and 4 prices, remember it is 3 prices because two of the products have a similar price so it just decides to leave one out, its almost as if two similar values cannot display on a slicer, the quantity of the last meal there on the meal slicer is actually 24 as well but because 24 is already there it decided to leave it out is there a fix for this? please help

Comment: so i added unique identifiers as i have discovered slicers cant display unique values but again the identifiers changes the values to text